# Align a relative positioned div to the right of container

Tags: html, css

I am using a WordPress page builder to build a page. You can see the page at https://rbose.in/matahari/ .

I have two columns(image to left and text to right) and have used some custom CSS to set offset border to the image. This is my code.

```
.home-feature {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.home-feature::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #F2C287;
  border-radius: 600px 600px 0 0;
  content: '';
      z-index: 1;
    
}
```

I am trying to align the image to the right edge of the column so that it's near the text. I know one way would be to add padding to the column but could anybody suggest a more tidier CSS way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Add `text-align: right;` on container?

Comment: Thank you that works it took some to understand why it works .